# SQL Localiza lançamentos duplicados e traz outro dado da tabela

Tags: sql

Bom dia pessoal! Não sou tão experiente ainda nos comandos SQL, por isso estou buscando os gurus aqui pra me dar uma força.

Vamos lá, tenho uma tabela onde são armazenados comprovantes de depósitos que os clientes enviam. Notamos que eventualmente há entradas de valores repetidos, por erros de lançamentos. Então criei uma chave que agrupa dados onde é possível identificar as duplicidades.

**SELECT ChaveControle FROM BancoCliente GROUP BY ChaveControle HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;**

O problema é que tenho dois campos com a mesma descrição e se der um update ambos vão sofrer o cancelamento. Para resolver o problema, preciso que o retorno deste select esteja dentro de outro select que trará o maior ID daquele resultado, com isso saberei que estou excluindo o segundo lançamento do cliente.

Preciso trazer o **Código** da mesma tabela. Para depois fazer um UPDATE utilizando o código.

CAMPOS DA TABELA **BANCOCLIENTE**
Código
ChaveControle

Comment: Suas chaves de controle repetidas se referem ao mesmo código de cliente ou a códigos de clientes diferentes? De qualquer maneira pesquise aqui no SOpt por exclusão de registros duplicados em SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Meu amigo chefancasb, muito grato!! Deu certinho e consegui chegar na informação que precisava.

O comando final ficou assim:

```
SELECT MAX(Código) as ID, ChaveControle
FROM BancoCliente
WHERE RIGHT(ChaveControle,1)<>"D"
GROUP BY ChaveControle
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Agora o que preciso é pegar esse resultado e realizar um **UPDATE** modificando o **STATUS** para **CANCELADO**. Acha que consegues?

> chefancasb

Answer (score -1):

Assumindo que a tabela tem, para alem dos campos que indica, um campo que identifica univocamente cada entrada, que par exemplo chamamos ID.

Com a expressão em baixo, obtemos apenas um resultado por cada ChaveControle duplicada.

```
SELECT * 
FROM BancoCliente
WHERE (ID, ChaveControle) IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID), ChaveControle
    FROM BancoCliente
    GROUP BY ChaveControle
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

O critério MAX pode ser alterado por outro qualquer (MIN, FIRST, LAST) que retorne um dos valores existentes.